# Tortoise svn Clean up not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, code-cleanup

While trying to update svn "403 forbidden error" is showing.I am not able to update the project.While entering into each folder i am able to update.But in one folder again same error occurs.Svn sometimes prompt to execute clean up command.But when clean up is given.It shows that **Clean up NOT WOrking.**I have seen lock may be the problem.but noting is locked.
When a new file added is updating it is not updating in my local copy..

**I checkout in new location now I am able to update but CLEAN UP is not working**

Can any one help??

Comment: @cowls ,matt thnk u 4 the advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the svn to next version.now everything works

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with the privileges. If cleanup doesn't work en you are sure you have the right credentials the best thing you can do is Checkout the project in a new folder and each file in this new folder. If you still get an error when you try to commit a file, something is wrong on the server.

Comment: no problem with privileges i guess.But once the svn path has been changed.but after commiting my edited files and then i have updated. I think it will then automatically point to new path.after these process.i faced these issues

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand. Can you please try to checkout your svn in a new folder and commit your edited files after the checkout is complete.

Comment: ya that workd.but still iam not able to clean the new one

Answer (score 2):

403 Forbidden means that you don't have permission to access a path referenced in your working copy. You'll have to ask your server administrator to check that out for you.

Comment: but i have permission to acces it.it shows that it is locked.but when i try to release lock,it shows that nothing is locked.